# Filtering results with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two dropdowns on my page.  First dropdown shows Authors for books and the other dropdown shows status's i.e Overdue or All.

If they choose Overdue then I need to return all books that have been borrowed more than a week ago so the dueback date (Datetime variable) will be taken into consideration.

I currently have this working correctly filtering on the Author as shown here:

```
  model.ListBooks = (from x in tempModel

                    where ((x.BookAuthor == model.ListAuthors.SelectedAuthor || model.ListAuthors.SelectedAuthor == null))

                    select x).ToList(); // Filter the results
```

But as soon as I pass in the additional search filter I.e status it fails to shows me any books that match the selected Author even though I haven't chosen a status this is what it currently looks like.

```
  model.ListBooks = (from x in tempModel
                     where (
                             (x.BookAuthor == model.ListAuthors.SelectedAuthor || model.ListAuthors.SelectedAuthor == null)
                           && 
                             (model.BookStatus.SelectedStatusId == (int)Enums.Registration.OverDue && x.DueBack < DateTime.Now.)
                           )
                           select x).ToList(); // Filter the results
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: DateTime.Now. is the period after Now typo only?

Comment: @Maku Yeah sorry thats a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query fails if selected status is not OverDue. In that case you have

```
where authorFilter && (false && dateFilter)
```

that gives you `false` for all books. Thus you have only two statuses, you can just add `status.SelectedStatusId != (int)Enums.Registration.OverDue` check just as you did with null-check for selected author:

```
var authors = model.ListAuthors;
var status = model.BookStatus;

model.ListBooks = (from x in tempModel
  where (authors.SelectedAuthor == null || x.BookAuthor == authors.SelectedAuthor) &&
        (status.SelectedStatusId != (int)Enums.Registration.OverDue || x.DueBack < DateTime.Now)
  select x).ToList();
```

I would use method syntax here to make query more readable:

```
var books = tempModel; // probably you will need IEnumerable<T> or IQueryable<T> here

if (model.ListAuthors.SelectedAuthor != null)
    books = books.Where(b => b.BookAuthor == model.ListAuthors.SelectedAuthor);

if (model.BookStatus.SelectedStatusId == (int)Enums.Registration.OverDue)
    books = books.Where(b => b.DueBack < DateTime.Now);

model.ListBooks = books.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I switched from what I have to the Syntax method works perfectly, I'm a little confused I've been on this project all day so this question may seem daft, but when they say "View list of all books overdue (borrowed more than 1 week ago)" does my current query take care of that? i.e the dueback date situation?

Comment: @ScottAtkinson I don't know how you book class looks like. But it should have two dates - one is when book was borrowed, and second is a due date (when it should be returned). I think you should two things 1) due date is less than current date - means book is overdue 2) borrow date is less than currentDate.AddDays(-7) - means it was borrowed more than week ago

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
(model.BookStatus.SelectedStatusId == (int)Enums.Registration.OverDue && x.DueBack < DateTime.Now.)
```

Should be instead:

```
(x.BookStatus.SelectedStatusId == (int)Enums.Registration.OverDue && x.DueBack < DateTime.Now.)
```

Because You like to compare element of LINQ query, not the model.

Comment: no its correct the way I have it, SelectedStatusId is a parameters passed in, its not part of the actual collection look at it as a Flag if that's sent then I need to filter on it i.e dueback date

Comment: is property DueBack nullable? I think DateTime default value (01.01.1900) could be always smaller than NOW.